# How to grey out spinner in Android?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I use two Spinner in my App. One of them is initially disabled because I need the user to select something in the first spinner to load the content of the second one.

I would like to change the design of the second spinner to show the user that the spinner is not active, eg. grey the spinner out. How can I achieve this?

If this is not possible how would you change this dialog to make it clear to the user that she has to select something in the first spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to setting as disabled, I don't know any other way to grey out.

Hide the second spinner until the first has no selection.
Or until it's in disabled state, the first visible option should show text related to the required selection eg: Select a Continent first

Comment: Thanks a good idea... greyed out text showing what to do first should do the trick.

Comment: ... A Spinner has always selected the first item. Therefor my first spinner has always selected something, and therefor the second spinner is always actice, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

The Spinner doesn't gray out when disabled, it's a bug that we fixed in FroYo (next version of Android.)

Comment: when will that be released approximately?