# how to prevent OnItemClickListener fires when checkbox is check

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclicklistener, android-checkbox

Today I faced the problem in spinner. when I create spinner with setOnItemClickListener.then I perform onCheckedChanged in my checkbox then ItemClick is also performing after onCheckedChanged.
how can i stop or prevent itemClick from firing when i click my checkbox?

Code:

Spinner

```
spinnerDrop.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), project.get(position).getProID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Checkbox

```
 chkSharedTask.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                sharedTaskVal = 1;
            }else{
                sharedTaskVal = 0;
            }

       }
  });
```

Comment: it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641879/how-do-i-make-a-spinners-disabled-state-look-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
spinnerDrop.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Inside setOnCheckedChangeListener()

Comment: Inside if(isChecked)